# Is it possible to attach a debugger to a dynamically linked library on the supported OS?

Tags: librarylink, debugging

Recently, I discovered that **LibraryLink** technique is a very useful tool to improve the performance of function. Firstly, I need to use LibraryLink template to write C/C++ program. Then compiling the program to dynamically linked library(i.e. ***.dll** file) via the `CCompilerDriver` package and C compiler. Please see [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8438/minimal-effort-method-for-integrating-c-functions-into-mathematica/8442#8442) answer.

If there is no error in your code, the compiling process will successful and no error information occurs. Unfortunately, there will always be some errors/bugs in the code in practice. For instance, today I applied a [right algorithm](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/119053/how-to-debug-the-c-code-for-librarylink) to LibraryLink template to calculate the nonzero values of B-spline basis, but I forgot the variable declaration of `saved`, and misuse the `MArgument_setReal()` operation.

In this process, I discovered that the debuging is very critical. While the error information that the `CreateLibrary[]`given is very limitted. Even if the compiling process is smoothly, the bug maybe exists. Please see [Update](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/119053/how-to-debug-the-c-code-for-librarylink) of that question. Although `NonzeroBasis[]` gives me the result, it is wrong and I cannot debug it to find where the error is.

Thank for Albert Retey and Szabolcs's suggestions [1](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/119053/how-to-debug-the-c-code-for-librarylink#comment321877_119053), [2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/119053/how-to-debug-the-c-code-for-librarylink#comment321883_119053), so I write a new thread here.

- If and how it is possible to attach a debugger to such a dynamically linked library on the supported operating systems?

Comment: The LibraryLink libraries are loaded into the kernel process, so you may attach a debugger to it (`$ProcessID` can be helpful) and then set a break point in one of your functions.

Comment: Strictly speaking this is not a Mathematica question.  It is about handling debuggers.  Yet I think it's still a very important question to ask on this site because many Mathematica users won't have experience with advanced use of debuggers, such as this, and could really use a short walkthrough on how to do it with various debuggers/IDEs/compilers ...

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this is possible. In Mathematica print out `$ProcessID` then in GDB you can use attach to attach to that process id and you should be able to debug.

Answer (score 4):

https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/118739/6804 discusses compiling a library link dll and attaching a debugger.

With say Visual Studio, you can just attach to process -> WolframKernel.exe after the dll has been loaded (via LibraryFunctionLoad).