# How to debug the C code for LibraryLink?

Tags: programming, librarylink, debugging

Recently, I use the C to rewrite a *Mathematica* function `NonzeroBasis[]`, please see [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/115107/how-to-compile-when-function-contains-condition) for fully descriptions.

Here, `NonzeroBasis[i,p,u,U]` calculates the values of $\{N_{i-p,p}(u),\cdots,N_{i-1,p}(u),N_{i,p}(u)\}$

The main algorithm as shown below:

[image]

#### LibraryLink Code

```c
#include "WolframLibrary.h"

DLLEXPORT int NonzeroBasis(WolframLibraryData libData, mint Argc, 
                           MArgument *Args, MArgument Res) {
  /*define the argument-varible*/
  mint i, p;
  mreal u;
  MTensor tensor_U;
  mreal *U;
  /*----------------------------*/
  mint j, r;
  mreal temp;
  mreal *left, *right, *N;
  MTensor tensor_N;
  mint type = MType_Real;
  mint dims[1];
  mint rank = 1;
  int err;
  /*assign the argument-value to argument-varible*/
  i = MArgument_getInteger(Args[0]);
  p = MArgument_getInteger(Args[1]);
  u = MArgument_getReal(Args[2]);
  tensor_U = MArgument_getMTensor(Args[3]);
  U = libData->MTensor_getRealData(tensor_U);
  dims[0] = p + 1;
  err = libData->MTensor_new(type, rank, dims, &tensor_N );
  N = libData->MTensor_getRealData(tensor_N);
  /*main implementation*/
  N[0] = 1.0;
  for(j = 1; j <= p; j++){
    left[j] = u - U[i+1-j];
    right[j] = U[i+j] - u;
    saved = 0.0;
    for(r = 0; r < j; r++){
        temp = N[r]/(right[r+1] + left[j-r]);
        N[r] = saved + right[r+1]*temp;
        saved = left[j-r]*temp;
    }
    N[j] = saved;
  }
  /*return the result*/
  MArgument_setReal(Res,tensor_N);
  return LIBRARY_NO_ERROR; 
}
```

However, when I compiled it via the following code in a **Simplified Chinese** operation system,

```
Needs["CCompilerDriver`"]
lib = 
  CreateLibrary[{"c:\\users\\Shutao TANG\\Desktop\\NonzeroBasis.c"}, 
                "NonzeroBasis", "Debug" -> False]
(*load the .dll to Mathematica*)
NonzeroBasis = 
  LibraryFunctionLoad[lib, "NonzeroBasis", 
                      {Integer, Integer, Real, {Real, 1}}, {Real, 1}]
```

it gives me this error(including **garbled** information)

[image]

#### Question

- How to debug the C code for LibraryLink? Because I cannot find useful information for debugging from `CreateLibrary::cmpper`.

---

#### Update

Now I also implement the main algorithm in *Mathematica*. **Note**: the start index for the *Mathematica* is `1`, while for C, the start index is `0`.

```
mmaNonzeroBasis[i_, p_, u_, U_] :=
  Module[{j, left, right, saved, r, temp, basis},
   left = right = ConstantArray[0.0, {p + 1}];
   basis = Prepend[ConstantArray[0.0, {p}], 1];
   For[j = 1, j <= p, j++,
     left[[j + 1]] = u - U[[i + 2 - j]];
     right[[j + 1]] = U[[i + j + 1]] - u;
     saved = 0.0;
     For[r = 0, r < j, r++,
       temp = basis[[r + 1]]/(right[[r + 2]] + left[[j - r + 1]]);
       basis[[r + 1]] = saved + right[[r + 2]]*temp;
       saved = left[[j - r + 1]]*temp
     ];
     basis[[j + 1]] = saved;
  ];
  basis
 ]
```

Thanks for Rolf Mertig's [revision](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/119053/how-to-debug-the-c-code-for-librarylink/119056#119056)

> - add the variable declaration `mreal saved` of `saved`
> - replace the `MArgument_setReal()` with `MArgument_setMTensor()`

```
knots = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10};
mmaNonzeroBasis[9, 4, 4.5, knots]
NonzeroBasis[9, 4, 4.5, knots]
BSplineBasis[{4, knots}, #, 4.5] & /@ Range[5, 9]
(*{0.0104167,0.380208,0.545139,0.0616319,0.00260417}*)
```

[image]

Which is very strange. I don't know why? Could someone help me find the reason?

Comment: not sure but to me the question is actually two fold: the garbled error messages indicate that there might be a problem with the messaging system and/or more specifically messages coming from the CreateLibrary/CCompilerDriver subsystem when used with (I guess) language settings set to chinese. Rolfs answer shows how the messages should look like and how they would help to eliminate the problems in your code. I would suggest to file a bug report to WRI about those messages...

Comment: The other part of the question (actually just the title) is about how to debug the actual C code, and to me that is equivalent to the question if and how it is possible to attach a debugger to such a dynamically linked library on the supported operating systems. Read as that it could trigger some really interesting answers, which I unfortunately can't provide and for which I couldn't find anything relevant quickly...

Comment: With your last edit you just changed what the question is ... Now the answers don't fit anymore.  "How to attach a debugger?" and "How to debug?" are two entirely different questions.  There are many more ways to debug than attaching a debugger.

Comment: I think it would be best if you reverted this edit and asked a separate question about the debugger.

Comment: @AlbertRetey Given the existing answers, attaching the debugger would best be made a separate question.  There are other ways to debug too (which I wrote an answer about), and why the error are garbled is yet again a separate question (also answered here).  I am very interesting in how to use a debugger with Mathematica and I do not know the answer to that.  But changing to question to that has just invalidated the answers ...

Comment: @Szabolcs OK, I will revert the question:)

Comment: @Shutao Thanks!  Don't forget to post the question about attaching a debugger!  I am very interested in that too.

Comment: @Szabolcs: I absolutely agree that making that an extra question and probably changing the title is a good idea. I also see and appreciate that both answer provide very valid and useful information. On the other hand everything but using a debugger to debug C code seems to be a workaround and not the "best way to debug". IMHO it is a shame that we Mathematica users do have to think about ways how to debug code at all, be it Mathematica or C/C++ via LibraryLink. I would expect useful debugging tools to be available out of the box for a language existing for 20+ years...

Comment: @Albert I agree, looking forward to seeing how to do it with a debugger (since I haven't really succeeded in that, though I tried).

Comment: @AlbertRetey Maybe you overlooked ["The design of the language makes all sorts of bugs that are common in other programming languages rare."](https://www.wolfram.com/language/elementary-introduction/47-debugging-your-code.html) and the "Tech Notes" instructing us that **A major goal of good language design is to encourage people to write correct code.** So either the language is not as good as it should be or we are not encouraged enough or we are not smart enough (I am not smart enough to write error-free code directly).

Comment: @Rolf: I was not even smart enough to recognize that providing a debugger would be a contradiction to the language design. That explains a lot, thanks for the hint! OK, lets go back to work and produce some of that error free code...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Update:**  The very likely reason for the garbled error messages is that you have a Chinese version of Visual Studio printing errors in Chinese, and there is a mismatch in the character encoding of these messages and how Mathematica tried to interpret them.

---

[`CreateLibrary`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CreateLibrary.html) has two very useful options: `"ShellCommandFunction"` and `"ShellOutputFunction"`.

Set them both to `Print`.

The first will print the compiler command line.  You will know how Mathematica is invoking the compiler precisely.  You can use the same command line in a terminal and compile without Mathematica if you wish.

The second will print the output from the compiler.  This usually has much more information about the error than what is shown through the `cmperr` messages.  I *always* use this option with `CreateLibrary` because the limited error information shown through the messages just isn't sufficient.

---

#### More tips to debug LibraryLink stuff

**Terminal output**

The first step is to make sure your code compiles.  Then you have to make sure it runs correctly.  It might crash, and there might be messages in the terminal about the cause of the crash.  Or you just might want to see debugging output written to the terminal.

Unfortunately it is not possible to see terminal output when running with the Front End.  It often helps if you run the kernel in command line mode (i.e. no front end), because you will be able to see any information output to the terminal.

It is also possible to run the kernel *with the front end*, yet still *attached to a terminal*.  [I wrote a blog post about how to do this on OS X and Windows.](http://szhorvat.net/pelican/displaying-debug-messages-coming-from-librarylink.html)  It should be possible to use the same ideas on Linux too.

In short: on Windows just set up `math.exe` to be used as the kernel instead of `MathKernel.exe`.

**Debugging features in [LTemplate](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/96127/12)**

I wrote the [LTemplate](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/96127/12) package to simplify working with LibraryLink.

*Note 1:* I recommend getting comfortable with plain LibraryLink before starting with LTemplate.  LTemplate makes LibraryLink easier to *use*, not easier to *learn*.

*Note 2:* LTemplate requires using C++, not C.  It is necessary to have at least  basic knowledge of C++ (basic understanding of classes, templates, exceptions).

LTemplate has a few features to simplify debugging:

The function `mma::print` can be used to print directly to the notebook instead of to the terminal, so you can see debugging output with the front end.

There is a streams interface for this: output to `mma::mout` the same way you would output to `std::cout` or `std:cerr` and flush the stream.  The output will be `Print`ed in the notebook.

Some C++ libraries, such as [Armadillo](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#config_hpp), can be set up to send their own debugging output to a stream.

There is a `massert` macro provided, which works like the standard `assert` macro, but instead of printing to `stderr` and terminating the kernel process, it prints to the notebook and simply returns from the library function.

LTemplate also catches any runaway C++ exceptions (which may come from a library you use), to prevent a kernel crash in this case.  For exceptions derived from `std::exception` it prints the description.

Finally, LTemplate makes error checking/handling in your library easy: use RAII and when there is a problem just throw an `mma::LibraryError` exception with a descriptive error message.  With good error checking you will be able to avoid problems more often.  With descriptive error messages you will be able to find the source of the problems faster.

Comment: @ShutaoTANG Could be this, depending on your version of Mathematica: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/41682/12

Comment: @ShutaoTANG Sorry, I didn't see this.  In that case it *should* work ... sorry for the obvious question, but did you load ``<<CCompilerDriver` `` before evaluating `CCompilers[]`?  What is very strange is that `CreateLibrary` works but `CCompilers[]` doesn't ...  Either both should work or neither.

Answer (score 7):

For me (Windows 10) I get a readable error message like
[image]

So I add  `mint saved;`.
Compiling again I get
[image]

which leads me to change your `MArgument_setReal(Res,tensor_N);` to `MArgument_setMTensor(Res,tensor_N);` and then things work.

BTW: I use

```
Needs["CCompilerDriver`"];
srccode="
#include \"WolframLibrary.h\"

DLLEXPORT int NonzeroBasis(WolframLibraryData libData, mint Argc, 
                           MArgument *Args, MArgument Res) {
  /*define the argument-varible*/
  mint i, p;
  mreal u;
  MTensor tensor_U;
  mreal *U;
  /*----------------------------*/
  mint j, r;
  mreal saved;
  mreal temp;
  mreal *left, *right, *N;
  MTensor tensor_N;
  mint type = MType_Real;
  mint dims[1];
  mint rank = 1;
  int err;
  /*assign the argument-value to argument-varible*/
  i = MArgument_getInteger(Args[0]);
  p = MArgument_getInteger(Args[1]);
  u = MArgument_getReal(Args[2]);
  tensor_U = MArgument_getMTensor(Args[3]);
  U = libData->MTensor_getRealData(tensor_U);
  dims[0] = p + 1;
  err = libData->MTensor_new(type, rank, dims, &tensor_N );
  N = libData->MTensor_getRealData(tensor_N);
  /*main implementation*/
  N[0] = 1.0;
  for(j = 1; j <= p; j++){
    left[j] = u - U[i+1-j];
    right[j] = U[i+j] - u;
    saved = 0.0;
    for(r = 0; r < j; r++){
        temp = N[r]/(right[r+1] + left[j-r]);
        N[r] = saved + right[r+1]*temp;
        saved = left[j-r]*temp;
    }
    N[j] = saved;
  }
  /*return the result*/
  MArgument_setMTensor(Res,tensor_N);
  return LIBRARY_NO_ERROR; 
}
";
lib = CreateLibrary[srccode, "NonzeroBasis"]
NonzeroBasis =
  LibraryFunctionLoad[lib, "NonzeroBasis",
                      {Integer, Integer, Real, {Real, 1}}, {Real, 1}]
```

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you need to define `MTensor` for variable `left` and `right`.
The modified code is:

```c
#include "WolframLibrary.h"

DLLEXPORT int NonzeroBasis(WolframLibraryData libData, mint Argc,
                       MArgument *Args, MArgument Res) {
  /*define the argument-varible*/
  mreal saved;
  mint i, p;
  mreal u;
  MTensor tensor_U;
  mreal *U;
  /*----------------------------*/
  mint j, r;
  mreal temp;
  mreal *left, *right, *N;
  MTensor left_t, right_t, tensor_N;
  mint type = MType_Real;
  mint dims[1];
  mint rank = 1;
  int err;
  /*assign the argument-value to argument-varible*/
  i = MArgument_getInteger(Args[0]);
  p = MArgument_getInteger(Args[1]);
  u = MArgument_getReal(Args[2]);
  tensor_U = MArgument_getMTensor(Args[3]);
  U = libData->MTensor_getRealData(tensor_U);
  dims[0] = p + 1;
  err = libData->MTensor_new(type, 1, dims, &tensor_N );
  N = libData->MTensor_getRealData(tensor_N);
  err = libData->MTensor_new(type, 1, dims, &left_t );
  left = libData->MTensor_getRealData(left_t);
  err = libData->MTensor_new(type, 1, dims, &right_t );
  right = libData->MTensor_getRealData(right_t);

  /*main implementation*/
  N[0] = 1.0;
  for(j = 1; j <= p; j++){
      left[j] = u - U[i+1-j];
      right[j] = U[i+j] - u;
      saved = 0.0;
      for(r = 0; r < j; r++){
          temp = N[r]/(right[r+1] + left[j-r]);
          N[r] = saved + right[r+1]*temp;
          saved = left[j-r]*temp;
      }
      N[j] = saved;
  }
  /*return the result*/
  MArgument_setMTensor(Res,tensor_N);
  return LIBRARY_NO_ERROR; 
}
```

This time it is giving the same results as other functions.

[image]

Comment: Amazing. How did you debug this? Or did you know that MTensor creature well enough?

Comment: @RolfMertig No I never used Library Link before, I just feel that the `left` and `right` pointer has not been defined a dimension, which doesn't look right in C. So I did same initialization with other tensor objects.