# Installing Microsoft C compiler on Windows 10

Tags: ccompilerdriver

On Windows 7 I was using Microsoft Visual C++ as CCompilerDriver. For this, the minimal solution is to install Microsoft .Net and then Microsoft SDK-7.1. There is no need to install Microsoft Visual Studio.

Now I am trying to install Microsoft C++ compiler to work with Mathematica 11 on Windows 10. The difference with Windows 7 is that in Windows 10 Microsoft .Net is a part of OS. Another difference is that SDK-10 does not contain C compiler, as I have found after installation. And it is impossible to install SDK-7.1 as it seems to be incompatible with the pre-installed .Net.

Could anybody propose a minimal solution to install the Microsoft C compiler on Windows 10?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about Mathematica or any of the other Wolfram Research software for which questions are accepted on this site.

Comment: @m_goldberg I don't agree with you here. Having a C compiler correctly installed is a prerequisite for the correct operation of Mathematica's Compile function with `CompilationTarget->"C" option. We have had many useful questions on that and stuff like CUDA. This is absolutely on-topic as far as I'm concerned.

Comment: I would try this: http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools  I don't know if it works because at the time when I installed this the only solution that seemed to be available was VS Community Edition (i.e. full IDE). So that's what I have, even though I don't use the IDE part. I do agree that this isn't really Mathematica related as the main part of the question seems to be how to avoid installing a full IDE ...

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries. Having a working internet connection is prerequisite for using curated data. Would you therefore accept questions about internet connection problems?

Comment: Thank you, Szabolcs, for a good advice! I have installed the Standalone Microsoft Visual C++ compiler and Mathematica 11 recognizes it as ccompilerdriver.

Comment: I have one concern, however. The installation path is "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0". Does x86 mean that this C++ compiler is 32 bit? On the download site there is no information on whether it is 32 bit or 64 bit.

Comment: What I am doing is high-performance computations with Mathematica in the area of solid-state physics (look up my papers), and on average using CompilationTarget->"C" gives a x2 speed-up. My question is relevant to Mathematica, and there were many threads of this type in the past. I am surprised that somebody is actively objecting discussing this important question here.

Comment: @m_goldberg Well, I've had problems getting past my corporate firewall to access curated data and have been asking questions about that. So, yes.

Comment: @DmitryGaranin this x86 has nor relationship with the compiler being 32 or 64 bit, as far as I know.

Comment: @DmitryGaranin What really matters is not whether the compiler itself is 32 or 64-bit executable.  The important thing is: does it generate 32 or 64-bit code?  If it works with `Compile` and a 64-bit version of Mathematica then it is definitely able to generate 64-bit code.

Comment: @DmitryGaranin Please post an answer to your own question.  I couldn't post it because I did not try that this works.  It is useful to document that it indeed does.

Comment: This question would 100% be better on some other stack site.  Just because it is a valid question doesn't make it on topic here

Comment: Maybe your LIB directory points to a 64-bit user32.lib and you're trying to compile a 32-bit executable, or the other way around. The compiler output (x86 or x64) must match the linked libraries

Answer (score 4):

I have installed the Standalone Microsoft Visual C++ compiler, as suggested by Szabolcs, [landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools](http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools). It is getting recognized by Mathematica 11 and working on Windows 10.

Note that you don't have to install Microsoft .NET since on Windows 10 it is a part of OS.

Comment: After install Encounter with a problem with Mathematica 11.1 on Windows 10.    `CreateExecutable::cmperr: Compile error: LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'user32.lib'`

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution doesn't seem to work for me either (I have Mathematica 10.2 on Win 10 64 bit). I also followed Szabolcs solution for making Mathematica 10.2 recognize the VisualStudio Compiler in "VisualStudioCompiler.m": [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/41682/c-compilation-not-working-with-visual-studio-2013/41691#41691). Funny enough, if I execute CCompilers[] Mathematica shows that it has found the VS compiler. But it says there "CompilerName" -> Automatic". Anyway trying to compile anything with CompilationTarget->"C" or the "hello world"-example fails.