# CreateLibrary fails... path to C header files problem?

Tags: compile, ccompilerdriver

How can I tell MMA where to find c header files for compilation? CreateLibrary is returning C1083 can't find stddef.h. Details follow...

Windows 10 - 1709 using Visual Studio 2015 (Community Edition, update 3), having modified VisualStudioCompiler.m to reference VS 2015)

by modding Line 280 to

```
$VisualStudioVersions = {"2015", "2013", "2012", "2010", "2008", "2005"}
```

and adding

```
installPath["2015"] := installPathFromEnvironment["VS140COMNTOOLS"]
```

Compiling generally works; the problem is with creating a library. Specifically the example in the documentation at CCompilerDriver/ref/CreateLibrary.

After

```
Needs["CCompilerDriver`"]
```

The documentation example continues with

```
add1src = "
 #include \"WolframLibrary.h\"
```

When the final library creation input

```
add1lib = CreateLibrary[add1src, "add1"]
```

is executed the result is

> "Compile error: "C:\ Program Files \ Wolfram Research \ \
>   Mathematica \ 11.0\ SystemFiles \ IncludeFiles \ C \ \
>   WolframLibrary.h(24): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: \
>   'stddef.h': No such file or directory "

Now. the opening lines of WolframLibrary.h are:

```
#ifndef WOLFRAMLIBRARY_H
#define WOLFRAMLIBRARY_H

#include "setjmp.h"

#define WolframLibraryVersion 3

#if !(defined(MATHEMATICA_KERNEL) || defined(MATHEMATICA_RUNTIME))

#include <stddef.h>
#include "dllexport.h"
#include "extern.h"
```

So it is < stddef.h > which can't be found.

Now, in Visual Studio unders Windows 10, sttdef.h is to be found in e.g.

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.16299.0\km\crt

(there are several, other subfolders of Include are 10.0. {14393, 10586,102140, 10150})

My questions are:

1/ Where does MMA look for e.g. stddef.h, i.e. where is the path specified

2/ How can I tell MMA to look in a location I specify, such as above

Many thanks!

**Extra Information per Szabolcs' suggestion**

After "ShellCommandFunction" -> Print, "ShellOutputFunction" -> Print

> call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   14.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" amd64
>
> cl.exe /LD /O2 /MT  /I "C:\Program Files\Wolfram
>   Research\Mathematica\11.0\SystemFiles\IncludeFiles\C" /I "C:\Program
>   Files\Wolfram
>   Research\Mathematica\11.0\SystemFiles\Links\MathLink\DeveloperKit\Windows-x86-64\CompilerAdditions\mldev64\include"
>   "C:\Users\Julian\AppData\Roaming\Mathematica\SystemFiles\LibraryResources\Windows-x86-64\Working-lotan-8708-15120-1\add1.c"
>   /link 
>   /implib:"C:\Users\Julian\AppData\Roaming\Mathematica\SystemFiles\LibraryResources\Windows-x86-64\Working-lotan-8708-15120-1\add1.lib"
>   /LIBPATH:"C:\Program Files\Wolfram
>   Research\Mathematica\11.0\SystemFiles\Links\MathLink\DeveloperKit\Windows-x86-64\CompilerAdditions\mldev64\lib"
>   /LIBPATH:"C:\Program Files\Wolfram
>   Research\Mathematica\11.0\SystemFiles\Libraries\Windows-x86-64" 
>   "ml64i4m.lib" 
>   /out:"C:\Users\Julian\AppData\Roaming\Mathematica\SystemFiles\LibraryResources\Windows-x86-64\Working-lotan-8708-15120-1\add1.dll"
>
> C:\Users\Julian\AppData\Roaming\Mathematica\SystemFiles\LibraryResources\Windows-x86-64\Working-lotan-8708-15120-1>call
>   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat"
>   amd64  Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.00.24215.1
>   for x64 Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
>
> add1.c C:\Program Files\Wolfram
>   Research\Mathematica\11.0\SystemFiles\IncludeFiles\C\WolframLibrary.h(24):
>   fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'stddef.h': No such file
>   or directory

Comment: When something like this happens, always look at the output from `"ShellCommandFunction" -> Print, "ShellOutputFunction" -> Print` (options to `CreateLibrary`) and include it in the question.

Comment: That said, the most likely reason is that you did not install the necessary headers with Visual Studio. I rarely use Windows, so I cannot give any specific details, but as I remember there are several components one can choose while installing VS.  The headers might be a separate one.   See e.g. here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/0f580a73-6f11-4aa6-abbe-6bf1438734c2/standard-files-stddefh-stringh-missing-in-visual-studio-2015-rc?forum=vclanguage

Comment: Personally, I don't install VS anymore just for use with Mathematica.  I only install the command line tools.  You can install the 2015 (not 2017!!) build tools and get rid of the VS GUI for good if you don't need it for anything else.  https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48159  The 2017 build tools only work with recent versions of Mma (11.2??) and the simple patch you show about won't be sufficient to use them.  I can confirm that Mathematica works fine with the 2015 build tools.

Comment: @Szabolcs I did actually do it your way with the build tools first, but now I need other VS capabilities. I'm afraid I don't understand your idea that I might not have installed the necessary headers since I provided a list of paths to stddef.h... did you mean some other headers? If so, which, why etc.? I think (but can't prove now) that because I wasn't planning to build apps with VS & did not initially install the Universal Windows App Development Tools (where they now live it seems) they were NOT included before - but they definitely exist now.

Comment: I mean that when you install VS, the installer presents you with a number of checkboxes.  Only checked components will be installed.  I suspect that a relevant component may not have been checked.  This is only a guess though.

Comment: @szabolcs understood :) but if you accept that the header file does now exist what *else* might have been left out of the VS installation? I'm no compiler expert, I personally have no idea!

Answer (score 4):

I doubt this is related to Mathematica. Can cl.exe compile any program containing `#include <stddef.h>` from a VS2015 command prompt?

These headers would be provided by selecting the "Universal CRT SDK" component when installing Visual Studio, but in this case also the OS version might be relevant.

From https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk

> Note: Windows 10 development targeting Windows 10 Creators Update (or later) requires Visual Studio 2017. This SDK will not be discovered by previous versions of Visual Studio.

For the specific questions, (1) Mathematica does nothing special, the issue is whether the compiler itself can find these and (2) additional include paths can be specified via the "IncludeDirectories" option, but that should not be necessary in view of (1).

Comment: That (other than MS putting the headers in a new place) makes sense & thanks for the link/quote. I'm adding a VS2017 install and will report how *that* goes

Comment: @JulianMoore If you have an older version of Mathematica that required the patch you mentioned, it won't be able to use VS2017.

Comment: @szabolcs I have 11.0.1... dare I hope that can use vs 2017? I was planning on making similar edits once the VS15 environment variable had been set up (which it isn't by default, but easy to do manually)

Comment: @Julian The same edit won't work for VS2017.  At least M11.2 is needed ... https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/140071/12

Comment: @szabolcs then can you recommend a VS version that will work with mma 11.0.1 and allow me to use CUDA (targeting gtx 1080 ti which 11.0.1 seems happy with using driver 388 etc) Cost prevents upgrading AGAIN.

Comment: Or should I use done other compiler entirely?

Comment: @ilian - I see from this Q https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/140071/getting-compile-to-work-with-visual-studio-2017-community-edition that CCompilerDriver was updated to use VSwhere. Is that version of CCompilerDriver available independently? Since it's a fix rather than a new feature it would seem reasonable...

Comment: @Julian Not released independently to my knowledge, though it may be worth asking support for it. Also I think it should be possible to use VS2015, just not with the latest SDK. Maybe reinstallation could help.

Comment: I'll ask support - thx.

Comment: + @szabolcs I have sent a message to support asking about CCompilerDriver independent release of CCompilerDriver. Meanwhile...  I was about to modify the VS 2015 installation again, decided to check I could compile something in VS 2015 with a #include <sttdef.h> (I could). Ran my create library test in MMA and... it worked. AFAICT I have done nothing else since posting the original Q except add (pointless) VS 2017 lines to CCompilerDriver. This is the 2nd time MMA + Compiler has suddenly gone from broken to working for no apparent reason. Not complaining, just confused. Very.

Comment: @JulianMoore As I remember, if some environment variables change, it is necessary to restart the Mathematica *Front End* as well before the changes are picked up (it's because the kernel process inherits the environment from the FE).  Could it be that you only restarted the kernel after installing the compiler?

Comment: @szabolcs could be... But I don't know: it's always the things one is not paying attention to that end up being significant.