# Instability, Courant Condition and Robustness about solving 2D+1 PDE

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, boundary-condition-at-infinity

After several discussions, I would like to focus on the robustness of solving 2D+1 PDE by considering all suggested methods from @xzczd (see [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/180453/solving-2d1-pde-with-pseudospectral-in-one-direction-with-periodic-boundary-con))
I found that the Ratio between the convection term and diffusion is crucial.
Here is the code.

```
Clear["Global`*"]
Clear[tosameorder, fix]
tosameorder[state_NDSolve`StateData, order_] := 
 state /. a_NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivativeFunction :> 
   NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative[a@"DerivativeOrder", 
    a@"Coordinates", "DifferenceOrder" -> order, 
    PeriodicInterpolation -> a@"PeriodicInterpolation"]

fix[endtime_, order_] := 
 Function[{ndsolve}, 
  Module[{state = 
     First[NDSolve`ProcessEquations @@ Unevaluated@ndsolve], 
    newstate}, newstate = tosameorder[state, order]; 
   NDSolve`Iterate[newstate, endtime];
   Unevaluated[ndsolve][[2]] /. NDSolve`ProcessSolutions@newstate], 
  HoldAll]
a = 1;
T = 1;
ωb = -15; ωt = 15;
A = 6.5;
γ = .1;
kT = 0.1;
φ = 0;

With[{u = u[t,θ, ω]}, 
eq = D[u, t] == -D[ω u,θ] - D[-A Sin[3θ] u, ω] + γ (1 + Sin[3θ])  kT  D[
   u, {ω, 2}] + γ  (1 + Sin[3θ]) D[ω u, ω];
ic = u == E^(-((ω^2 +(θ+Pi/4)^2)/(2 a^2))) 1/(2 π a) /. t -> 0];
ufun = NDSolveValue[{eq, ic, u[t, -π, ω] == u[t, π, ω], 
 u[t,θ, ωb] == 0, u[t,θ, ωt] == 0}, u, {t, 0, T}, {θ, -π, π}, {ω, ωb, ωt}, 
      Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
       "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
         "MaxPoints" -> {81, 51}, 
         "MinPoints" -> {41, 31}}}]; // AbsoluteTiming
plots = Table[
Plot3D[Abs[ufun[t,θ, ω]], {θ, -π, π}, {ω, ωb, ωt}, AxesLabel -> Automatic, 
 PlotPoints -> 30, BoxRatios -> {Pi, ωb, 1}, 
 ColorFunction -> "LakeColors", PlotRange -> All], {t, 0, T, 
 T/10}]; // AbsoluteTiming
ListAnimate[plots]
```

One can see that the coefficient of diffusion term (2nd-order term) is really small ($0.1*0.1*sin(3\theta)$) especially when $sin(3\theta)=-1$, how could it possible satisfy the Courant condition with such vanishing diffusion term?

The below is the result:
[image]

What I expect is the something similar to following (obtain by adding artificial diffusion)

[image]

The main question is the robustness about solving this partially convection-dominated problem in a efficient and stable way. Many thanks.

Note about artificial diffusion:

```
Max[γ[θ], 0.3] D[ u, {ω, 2}]
```

This is how I put the artificial diffusion. But for the problem, the angle-dependent diffusion and convection are different.

Full code is here, it's a little bit messy:

```
Clear["Global`*"]
(*//////////////////////////////////////         parameters         \
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////\
*)

n = 3; 
ϕ = π/2; vg0 = 5;
vg[t_] := vg[t] = vg0;
(*vg[t_]:=vg[t]=2vg0*1/(\[ExponentialE]^(k(t-Tp1))+1)-vg0;*)
(*vg[t_]:=vg[t]=2vg0*1/(\[ExponentialE]^(k(t-Tp1))+1)-2vg0*1/(\
\[ExponentialE]^(k(t-Tp2))+1)+vg0;*)


τi = 3; Γ = 10; 

Vb = 0; μ[α_] := (-1)^(α + 1) Vb/2  ;


XTicks1 = Table[2 π*j, {j, -10, 10}];
XTicks2 = Table[π/6*j, {j, -10, 10}];
YTicks = Table[2 π*j, {j, -10, 10}];



(*//////////////////////////////////////         Karrasch poles and \
coefficients          \
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////\
*)

Np = 25; M = 2 Np;
B = Normal[
   SparseArray[{Band[{2, 1}] -> 
      Table[N[1/(2 Sqrt[(2 n - 1) (2 n + 1)])], {n, 1, M - 1}], 
     Band[{1, 2}] -> 
      Table[N[1/(2 Sqrt[(2 n - 1) (2 n + 1)])], {n, 1, M - 1}]}, M]];
{bvals, bvecs} = Eigensystem[B];
Zp = Table[Abs[N[1/bvals[[2 p]]]], {p, 1, Np}];
Rp = Table[
   N[(Normalize[bvecs[[2 p]]][[1]]/(2 bvals[[2 p]]))^2], {p, 1, Np}];

(*/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////\
*)

σ0[θ_, V_, τ0_, Γ_, 
   Vg_, ϕ_] := σ0[θ, V, τ0, Γ, 
    Vg, ϕ] = 
   1/2 - I/(
     4 π) (PolyGamma[
        1/2 - I/(
          2 π) (τ0 (Sin[n θ + ϕ] - 
               Sin[n θ]) - V/2 + Vg) + Γ/(
         4 π)] - 
       PolyGamma[
        1/2 + I/(
          2 π) (τ0 (Sin[n θ + ϕ] - 
               Sin[n θ]) - V/2 + Vg) + Γ/(
         4 π)] + 
       PolyGamma[
        1/2 - I/(
          2 π) (τ0 (Sin[n θ + ϕ] - 
               Sin[n θ]) + V/2 + Vg) + Γ/(
         4 π)] - 
       PolyGamma[
        1/2 + I/(
          2 π) (τ0 (Sin[n θ + ϕ] - 
               Sin[n θ]) + V/2 + Vg) + Γ/(
         4 π)]);
τ[θ_, V_, τ0_, Γ_, 
   Vg_, ϕ_] := τ[θ, V, τ0, Γ, 
    Vg, ϕ] = -τ0 n (Cos[n θ + ϕ] - 
      Cos[n  θ]) σ0[θ, 
     V, τ0, Γ, Vg, ϕ];
σ1[θ_, V_, τ0_, Γ_, 
   Vg_, ϕ_] := σ1[θ, V, τ0, Γ, 
    Vg, ϕ] = 
   1/(8 π^2 Γ)*(PolyGamma[1, 
        1/2 - I/(
          2 π) (τ0 (Sin[n θ + ϕ] - 
               Sin[n θ]) - V/2 + Vg) + Γ/(
         4 π)] + 
       PolyGamma[1, 
        1/2 + I/(
          2 π) (τ0 (Sin[n θ + ϕ] - 
               Sin[n θ]) - V/2 + Vg) + Γ/(
         4 π)] + 
       PolyGamma[1, 
        1/2 - I/(
          2 π) (τ0 (Sin[n θ + ϕ] - 
               Sin[n θ]) + V/2 + Vg) + Γ/(
         4 π)] + 
       PolyGamma[1, 
        1/2 + I/(
          2 π) (τ0 (Sin[n θ + ϕ] - 
               Sin[n θ]) + V/2 + Vg) + Γ/(
         4 π)]) - \!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(∑\), \(p = 
       1\), \(Np\)]\(Rp[\([\)\(p\)\(]\)] \((
\*FractionBox[\(3 
\*SuperscriptBox[\((τ0 \((Sin[n\ θ + ϕ] - \ 
                 Sin[n\ θ])\) - V/2 + 
              Vg)\), \(2\)] \((Γ/2 + 
             Zp[\([\)\(p\)\(]\)])\) - 
\*SuperscriptBox[\((Γ/2 + 
             Zp[\([\)\(p\)\(]\)])\), \(3\)]\), 
SuperscriptBox[\((
\*SuperscriptBox[\((\ τ0 \((Sin[n\ θ + ϕ] - \ 
                  Sin[n\ θ])\) - V/2 + Vg)\), \(2\)] + 
\*SuperscriptBox[\((Γ/2 + 
               Zp[\([\)\(p\)\(]\)])\), \(2\)])\), \(3\)]] + 
\*FractionBox[\(3 
\*SuperscriptBox[\((τ0 \((Sin[n\ θ + ϕ] - \ 
                 Sin[n\ θ])\) + V/2 + 
              Vg)\), \(2\)] \((Γ/2 + 
             Zp[\([\)\(p\)\(]\)])\) - 
\*SuperscriptBox[\((Γ/2 + 
             Zp[\([\)\(p\)\(]\)])\), \(3\)]\), 
SuperscriptBox[\((
\*SuperscriptBox[\((\ τ0 \((Sin[n\ θ + ϕ] - \ 
                  Sin[n\ θ])\) + V/2 + Vg)\), \(2\)] + 
\*SuperscriptBox[\((Γ/2 + 
               Zp[\([\)\(p\)\(]\)])\), \(2\)])\), \(3\)]])\)\)\);
Uprime[θ_, τ0_, ϕ_] := τ0 n Cos[n θ];

mol[m_Integer, n_Integer] := {"MethodOfLines", 
  "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", "MaxPoints" -> m, 
    "MinPoints" -> n}}
τeff = 
  FunctionInterpolation[-τi n Cos[n θ] + τ[θ, 
     Vb, τi, Γ, 
     vg0, ϕ], {θ, -π, π}];
γ = 
  FunctionInterpolation[(τi n (Cos[n θ + ϕ] - 
        Cos[n  θ]))^2 σ1[θ, 
     Vb, τi, Γ, 
     vg0, ϕ], {θ, -π, π}, AccuracyGoal -> 5, 
   InterpolationPrecision -> MachinePrecision];
Plot[{τeff[θ], γ[θ]}, {θ, -π, \
π}, PlotRange -> All]
a = 0.7;
T = 20;
ωb = -8;
ωt = 8;
θ0 = -π/4;
L = 1;
With[{u = u[t, θ, ω]}, 
  eq = D[u, t] == -ω D[ u, θ] - 
     1/L*τeff[θ] D[u, ω] + 
     Re[γ[θ]] D[ ω u, ω] + 
     Max[γ[θ], 0.3] D[ u, {ω, 2}];
  ic = u == 
     E^(-(ω^2 + (θ + π/
                4)^2)/(2 a^2))/(2  π a^2) /. t -> 0];

ufun = NDSolveValue[{eq, ic, 
     u[t, -π, ω] == u[t, π, ω], 
     u[t, θ, ωb] == 0, u[t, θ, ωt] == 0}, 
    u, {t, 0, 
     T}, {θ, -π, π}, {ω, ωb, ωt}, 
    Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
      "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
        "MaxPoints" -> {41, 61}, "MinPoints" -> {41, 61}, 
        "DifferenceOrder" -> 4}}]; // AbsoluteTiming
(*Plot3D[ufun[T,θ,ω],{θ,-π,π},{ω,\
ωb,ωt},PlotRange\[Rule]All,AxesLabel\[Rule]Automatic,\
PlotPoints\[Rule]30,ColorFunction\[Rule]"LakeColors"]*)
plots = Table[
    Plot3D[Abs[
      ufun[t, θ, ω]], {θ, -π, π}, {\
ω, ωb, ωt}, PlotRange -> All, 
     AxesLabel -> Automatic, PlotPoints -> 30, 
     ColorFunction -> "LakeColors"], {t, 0, T, 
     T/50}]; // AbsoluteTiming
ListAnimate[plots] // AbsoluteTiming
```

**Stable Julia code for the same problem**:
Matrix of 2D+1 PDE

```
function F_eff(x, Gamma, Delta, Q, EpOm, A)
    return -A*sin(x + Delta)
end

# effective friction
function gamma_eff(x, Gamma, Delta, Q, EpOm, A)
    return Gamma
end

# effective diffusion
function D_eff(x, Gamma, Delta, Q, EpOm, A, kBT)
    return 2.0*kBT*Gamma
end

function make_FPE_matrix(xi,vj,Gamma, Delta, Q, EpOm, A, kBT)

    Nx = length(xi)
    Nv = length(vj)
    hx = xi[2]-xi[1]
    hv = vj[2]-vj[1]

    mat = zeros(Float64, Nx*Nv+1, Nx*Nv)

    for i=0:(Nx-1)
        for j=0:(Nv-1)

            mat[i*(Nv)+j+1,i*(Nv)+j+1] = -D_eff( xi[i+1], Gamma, Delta, Q, EpOm, A, kBT)/(4*hv^2)

            # -d/dx (v P)
            if i == 0
                mat[i*(Nv)+j+1, (Nx-1)*(Nv)+j+1] = vj[j+1]/(2*hx) # PBC
            end
            if i > 0
                mat[i*(Nv)+j+1, (i-1)*(Nv)+j+1] = vj[j+1]/(2*hx)
            end
            if i < Nx-1
                mat[i*(Nv)+j+1, (i+1)*(Nv)+j+1] = -vj[j+1]/(2*hx)
            end
            if i == Nx-1
                mat[i*(Nv)+j+1, (0)*(Nv)+j+1] = -vj[j+1]/(2*hx)   # PBC
            end


            if j > 0
                mat[i*(Nv)+j+1, (i)*(Nv)+(j-1)+1] = F_eff(xi[i+1],Gamma, Delta, Q, EpOm, A)/(2*hv) -
                    gamma_eff(xi[i+1],Gamma, Delta, Q, EpOm, A)*vj[j+1-1]/(2*hv)
                if j> 1
                    mat[i*(Nv)+j+1, (i)*(Nv)+(j-2) + 1] = 0.5*D_eff(xi[i+1], Gamma, Delta, Q, EpOm, A, kBT)/(4*hv^2)
                end
            end
            if j < Nv-1
                mat[i*(Nv)+j+1, (i)*(Nv)+(j+1)+1] = -F_eff(xi[i+1],Gamma, Delta, Q, EpOm, A)/(2*hv) +
                    gamma_eff(xi[i+1], Gamma, Delta, Q, EpOm, A)*vj[j+1+1]/(2*hv)
                if j < Nv-2
                    mat[i*(Nv)+j+1, (i)*(Nv)+(j+2)+1] = 0.5*D_eff(xi[i+1], Gamma, Delta, Q, EpOm, A, kBT)/(4*hv^2)
                end
            end

        end
    end

    for i = 1:Nx*Nv
         mat[end,i] = hx*hv
    end

    return mat
end
```

**Update (9/4)** 
I try to run the compiled code (with VS2017 community). Here is my code:

```
Clear["Global`*"]
(*//////////////////////////////////////         parameters         \
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////\
*)

n = 3; 
ϕ = π/2; vg0 = 5;
vg[t_] := vg[t] = vg0;


τi = 3; Γ = 10; 

Vb = 0; μ[α_] := (-1)^(α + 1) Vb/2  ;


XTicks1 = Table[2 π*j, {j, -10, 10}];
XTicks2 = Table[π/6*j, {j, -10, 10}];
YTicks = Table[2 π*j, {j, -10, 10}];



(*//////////////////////////////////////         Karrasch poles and \
coefficients          \
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////\
*)

Np = 25; M = 2 Np;
B = Normal[
   SparseArray[{Band[{2, 1}] -> 
      Table[N[1/(2 Sqrt[(2 n - 1) (2 n + 1)])], {n, 1, M - 1}], 
     Band[{1, 2}] -> 
      Table[N[1/(2 Sqrt[(2 n - 1) (2 n + 1)])], {n, 1, M - 1}]}, M]];
{bvals, bvecs} = Eigensystem[B];
Zp = Table[Abs[N[1/bvals[[2 p]]]], {p, 1, Np}];
Rp = Table[
   N[(Normalize[bvecs[[2 p]]][[1]]/(2 bvals[[2 p]]))^2], {p, 1, Np}];

(*/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////\
*)

σ0[θ_, V_, τ0_, Γ_, 
   Vg_, ϕ_] := σ0[θ, V, τ0, Γ, 
    Vg, ϕ] = 
   1/2 - I/(
     4 π) (PolyGamma[
        1/2 - I/(
          2 π) (τ0 (Sin[n θ + ϕ] - 
               Sin[n θ]) - V/2 + Vg) + Γ/(
         4 π)] - 
       PolyGamma[
        1/2 + I/(
          2 π) (τ0 (Sin[n θ + ϕ] - 
               Sin[n θ]) - V/2 + Vg) + Γ/(
         4 π)] + 
       PolyGamma[
        1/2 - I/(
          2 π) (τ0 (Sin[n θ + ϕ] - 
               Sin[n θ]) + V/2 + Vg) + Γ/(
         4 π)] - 
       PolyGamma[
        1/2 + I/(
          2 π) (τ0 (Sin[n θ + ϕ] - 
               Sin[n θ]) + V/2 + Vg) + Γ/(
         4 π)]);
τ[θ_, V_, τ0_, Γ_, 
   Vg_, ϕ_] := τ[θ, V, τ0, Γ, 
    Vg, ϕ] = -τ0 n (Cos[n θ + ϕ] - 
      Cos[n  θ]) σ0[θ, 
     V, τ0, Γ, Vg, ϕ];
σ1[θ_, V_, τ0_, Γ_, 
   Vg_, ϕ_] := σ1[θ, V, τ0, Γ, 
    Vg, ϕ] = 
   1/(8 π^2 Γ)*(PolyGamma[1, 
        1/2 - I/(
          2 π) (τ0 (Sin[n θ + ϕ] - 
               Sin[n θ]) - V/2 + Vg) + Γ/(
         4 π)] + 
       PolyGamma[1, 
        1/2 + I/(
          2 π) (τ0 (Sin[n θ + ϕ] - 
               Sin[n θ]) - V/2 + Vg) + Γ/(
         4 π)] + 
       PolyGamma[1, 
        1/2 - I/(
          2 π) (τ0 (Sin[n θ + ϕ] - 
               Sin[n θ]) + V/2 + Vg) + Γ/(
         4 π)] + 
       PolyGamma[1, 
        1/2 + I/(
          2 π) (τ0 (Sin[n θ + ϕ] - 
               Sin[n θ]) + V/2 + Vg) + Γ/(
         4 π)]) - \!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(∑\), \(p = 
       1\), \(Np\)]\(Rp[\([\)\(p\)\(]\)] \((
\*FractionBox[\(3 
\*SuperscriptBox[\((τ0 \((Sin[n\ θ + ϕ] - \ 
                 Sin[n\ θ])\) - V/2 + 
              Vg)\), \(2\)] \((Γ/2 + 
             Zp[\([\)\(p\)\(]\)])\) - 
\*SuperscriptBox[\((Γ/2 + 
             Zp[\([\)\(p\)\(]\)])\), \(3\)]\), 
SuperscriptBox[\((
\*SuperscriptBox[\((\ τ0 \((Sin[n\ θ + ϕ] - \ 
                  Sin[n\ θ])\) - V/2 + Vg)\), \(2\)] + 
\*SuperscriptBox[\((Γ/2 + 
               Zp[\([\)\(p\)\(]\)])\), \(2\)])\), \(3\)]] + 
\*FractionBox[\(3 
\*SuperscriptBox[\((τ0 \((Sin[n\ θ + ϕ] - \ 
                 Sin[n\ θ])\) + V/2 + 
              Vg)\), \(2\)] \((Γ/2 + 
             Zp[\([\)\(p\)\(]\)])\) - 
\*SuperscriptBox[\((Γ/2 + 
             Zp[\([\)\(p\)\(]\)])\), \(3\)]\), 
SuperscriptBox[\((
\*SuperscriptBox[\((\ τ0 \((Sin[n\ θ + ϕ] - \ 
                  Sin[n\ θ])\) + V/2 + Vg)\), \(2\)] + 
\*SuperscriptBox[\((Γ/2 + 
               Zp[\([\)\(p\)\(]\)])\), \(2\)])\), \(3\)]])\)\)\);
Uprime[θ_, τ0_, ϕ_] := τ0 n Cos[n θ];

mol[m_Integer, n_Integer] := {"MethodOfLines", 
  "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", "MaxPoints" -> m, 
    "MinPoints" -> n}}
τeff = 
  FunctionInterpolation[-τi n Cos[n θ] + τ[θ, 
     Vb, τi, Γ, 
     vg0, ϕ], {θ, -π, π}];
γ = 
  FunctionInterpolation[(τi n (Cos[n θ + ϕ] - 
        Cos[n  θ]))^2 σ1[θ, 
     Vb, τi, Γ, 
     vg0, ϕ], {θ, -π, π}, AccuracyGoal -> 5, 
   InterpolationPrecision -> MachinePrecision];
Plot[{τeff[θ], γ[θ]}, {θ, -π, \
π}, PlotRange -> All]
a = 0.7;
T = 20;
ωb = -8;
ωt = 8;
θ0 = -π/4;
L = 1;
Clear[τeff, γ]
points@θ = 100; points@ω = 50;
delta@θ = (Pi + Pi)/(points@θ - 1);
delta@ω = (ωt - ωb)/(points@ω - 1);
τefflst = 
  Chop@N@Array[
     Function[θ, -τi n Cos[n θ] + τ[θ, Vb, τi, Γ, vg0, ϕ]], points@θ, {-π, π}];
γlst = 
  Chop@Array[
     Function[θ, (τi n (Cos[n θ + ϕ] - Cos[n θ]))^2 σ1[θ, Vb, τi, Γ, vg0, ϕ]], 
     points@θ, {-π, π}];

With[{u = u[θ, ω]}, 
  rhs2 = -ω ct@D[u, θ] - 1/L τeff[θ] ct@D[u, ω] + 
         γ[θ] ct@D[ω u, ω] + γ[θ] fw@D[bw@D[u, ω], ω]; 
  iclst2 = Table[E^(-((ω^2 + (θ + π/4)^2)/(2 a^2)))/(2 π a^2), 
                 {θ, -Pi, Pi, delta@θ}, {ω, ωb, ωt, delta@ω}]];

rt = RescalingTransform[{{-Pi, Pi}, {ωb, ωt}}, {{1, points@θ}, {1, points@ω}}];
rttheta = RescalingTransform[{{-Pi, Pi}}, {{1, points@θ}}];

With[{rc = RuleCondition, cg = Compile`GetElement}, 
  rhsfunc2 = Hold@
            Compile[{{u, _Real, 2}, {τeff, _Real, 1}, {γ, _Real, 1}}, 
             Table[rhs2, {θ, -Pi, Pi, delta@θ}, {ω, ωb, ωt, delta@ω}], 
             RuntimeOptions -> EvaluateSymbolically -> False, CompilationTarget -> C] /. 
           OwnValues@rhs2 /. 
          u[theta_, omega_] :> 
           rc@(cg[u, Mod[#, points@θ - 1, 1], Mod[#2, points@ω - 1, 1]] & @@
               Round@rt@{theta, omega}) /. (coef : τeff | γ)[theta_] :> 
          rc@(cg[coef, First@Round@rttheta@{theta}]) /. DownValues@delta /. 
       DownValues@points /. Flatten[OwnValues /@ Unevaluated@{ωb, ωt}] // 
     ReleaseHold // Last];
T = 30;
ulstfunc2 = 
   NDSolveValue[{u'[t] == rhsfunc2[u[t], τefflst, γlst], u[0] == iclst2}, 
    u, {t, 0, T}, MaxSteps -> Infinity]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {36.177260, Null} *)

lst = Table[
   ListPlot3D[ulstfunc2[t]\[Transpose], PlotRange -> All, 
    DataRange -> {{-Pi, Pi}, {ωb, ωt}}], {t, 0, 5, 1/20}];    
ListAnimate@lst
```

There is an error message:

```
CompiledFunction::rterr: -- Message text not found -- (compiledFunction5) (8)
```

Comment: See section "Stabilization of Convection-Dominated Equations" in [this guide](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/FiniteElementBestPractice.html). Note that this is also an ongoing research topic.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Thanks for the suggestion. Actually, the second animation is obtained from adding artificial diffusion as suggested in the documentation. In question is "How far away is solution relative to the actual solution" and "Can we actually improve the stability by specifying a proper grids or boundary condition". Of course, the Courant condition is an important issue but hard to control since time-step is adaptive, which is not able to modify manually.

Comment: "What I expect is the something similar to following (obtain by adding artificial diffusion)" How do you add the artificial diffusion? Can you include the specific setting?

Comment: @xzczd I put the code in my question. The idea is to keep some minimal value of diffusion such that the solution is still stable.

Comment: Well, I'm afraid the new sample isn't that convictive, the equation therein is quite different from the one in the first sample.

Comment: @xzczd Okay, But my friend using julia to compute the first one , and he arrive something similar to the second one.

Comment: This isn't convictive either, as long as we don't see the Julia code. Actually I've just tried disretizing the equation myself (with simple forward and central difference formula, as you've mentioned before), only to discover the solution becomes unstable in a even faster way. Is it convenient for you to make the Julia code public? If not, can you show us the specific difference scheme used in the Julia code?

Comment: The thing is that we still need some strategy to choose the grids to make it stable.

Comment: The Julia code is incomplete. Anyway, I managed to find a hint from it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

OK, since neither of the default difference scheme nor the [`fix`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/129193/1871) function works properly on this PDE, let's discretize the spatial derivative all by ourselves in a way different from that in `NDSolve` or in `fix[…, …]@NDSolve`.

The spatial discretization will be done in the following way:
\begin{aligned}
\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}\Biggl|_{x=x_i} \approx & \frac{f(x_i+h)-2f(x_i)+f(x_i-h)}{h^2}
\\
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\Biggl|_{x=x_i} \approx & \frac{f(x_i+h)-f(x_i-h)}{2h}
\\
\frac{\partial (x f)}{\partial x}\Biggl|_{x=x_i} \approx & \frac{(x_i+h) f(x_i+h)-(x_i-h)f(x_i-h)}{2h}
\end{aligned}

Notice the difference formula for $\frac{\partial (x f)}{\partial x}\Bigl|_{x=x_i}$ is critical here, because it produces a result **different** from

$$\frac{\partial (x f)}{\partial x}\Biggl|_{x=x_i}=\left(x\frac{\partial  f}{\partial x}+f\frac{\partial  x}{\partial x}\right)\Biggl|_{x=x_i}\approx x_i \frac{f(x_i+h)-f(x_i-h)}{2h}+f(x_i)$$

Periodic b.c. will be set in both directions because it's relatively easier to implement. Since the Dirichlet b.c. in $\omega$ direction is just an approximation for b.c. at infinity, this should not have any significant influence on the result.

The remaining work is just coding:

```
ωb = -5; ωt = 5;
a = 1; A = 6.5; γ = .1; kT = 0.1; φ = 0;

ClearAll[fw, bw, ct]
SetAttributes[#, HoldAll] & /@ {fw, bw, ct};
fw@D[expr_, x_] := Subtract @@ (expr /. {{x -> x + delta@x}, {x -> x}})/delta@x
bw@D[expr_, x_] := Subtract @@ (expr /. {{x -> x}, {x -> x - delta@x}})/delta@x
ct@D[expr_, x_] := 
 Subtract @@ (expr /. {{x -> x + delta@x}, {x -> x - delta@x}})/(2 delta@x)

Clear[delta]
delta[a_ + b_] := delta@a + delta@b
delta[k_. delta[_]] := 0

points@θ = 100; points@ω = 50;
delta@θ = (Pi + Pi)/(points@θ - 1);
delta@ω = (ωt - ωb)/(points@ω - 1);
With[{u = u[θ, ω]}, 
  rhs =-ct@D[ω u, θ] - ct@D[-A Sin[3 θ] u, ω] + 
       γ (1 + Sin[3 θ]) kT bw@D[fw@D[u, ω], ω] + γ (1 + Sin[3 θ]) ct@D[ω u, ω];
  iclst = Table[
                E^(-((ω^2 + (θ + Pi/4)^2)/(2. a^2))) 1/(2 π a), 
                {θ, -Pi, Pi, delta@θ}, {ω, ωb, ωt, delta@ω}]
  ];

rt = RescalingTransform[{{-Pi, Pi}, {ωb, ωt}}, {{1, points@θ}, {1, points@ω}}];

With[{rc = RuleCondition, cg = Compile`GetElement}, 
  rhsfunc = Hold@Compile[{{u, _Real, 2}},            
             Table[rhs, {θ, -Pi, Pi, delta@θ}, {ω, ωb, ωt, delta@ω}], 
             RuntimeOptions -> EvaluateSymbolically -> False, 
             CompilationTarget -> C] /. OwnValues@rhs /. 
          u[theta_, omega_] :> 
           rc@(cg[u, Mod[#, points@θ - 1, 1], Mod[#2, points@ω - 1, 1]] & @@
               Round /@ rt@{theta, omega}) /. DownValues@delta /. 
       DownValues@points /. Flatten[OwnValues /@ Unevaluated@{ωb, ωt}] // 
     ReleaseHold // Last];

T = 30;
ulstfunc = NDSolveValue[{u'[t] == rhsfunc[u[t]], u[0] == iclst}, u, {t, 0, T}, 
    MaxSteps -> Infinity]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {33.1812583, Null} *)

lst = Table[
   ListPlot3D[ulstfunc[t]\[Transpose], PlotRange -> All, 
    DataRange -> {{-Pi, Pi}, {ωb, ωt}}], {t, 0, T, 1}];   
ListAnimate@lst
```

[image]

The result seems to be what you're expecting.

If you don't have a C compiler installed, take the `CompilationTarget` option and `// Last` away. I do recommend you to install one though.

Some advanced technique has been used in this code piece to make the discretization less tedious. To understand it better, you may want to read the following posts:

[When should I, and when should I not, set the HoldAll attribute on a function I define?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4126/1871)

[Is there a way to simplify this replacement rule](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/33056/1871)

[How to make the code inside Compile conciser without hurting performance?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/47485/1871)

[Why is CompilationTarget -> C slower than directly writing with C?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/132130/1871)

[Replacement inside held expression](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29317/1871)

---

## Update: Uncompilable coefficient function treatment

The coefficients of equation solved above is [compilable](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1096/1871). When they're not, such as in your 2nd code sample, some further modification is needed. The key idea is calculating coefficient values at grid points first and pass the value list to `Compile`:

```
Clear[τeff, γ]
points@θ = 100; points@ω = 50;
delta@θ = (Pi + Pi)/(points@θ - 1);
delta@ω = (ωt - ωb)/(points@ω - 1);
τefflst = 
  Chop@N@Array[
     Function[θ, -τi n Cos[n θ] + τ[θ, Vb, τi, Γ, vg0, ϕ]], points@θ, {-π, π}];
γlst = 
  Chop@Array[
     Function[θ, (τi n (Cos[n θ + ϕ] - Cos[n θ]))^2 σ1[θ, Vb, τi, Γ, vg0, ϕ]], 
     points@θ, {-π, π}];

With[{u = u[θ, ω]}, 
  rhs2 = -ω ct@D[u, θ] - 1/L τeff[θ] ct@D[u, ω] + 
         γ[θ] ct@D[ω u, ω] + γ[θ] fw@D[bw@D[u, ω], ω]; 
  iclst2 = Table[E^(-((ω^2 + (θ + π/4)^2)/(2 a^2)))/(2 π a^2), 
                 {θ, -Pi, Pi, delta@θ}, {ω, ωb, ωt, delta@ω}]];

rt = RescalingTransform[{{-Pi, Pi}, {ωb, ωt}}, {{1, points@θ}, {1, points@ω}}];
rttheta = RescalingTransform[{{-Pi, Pi}}, {{1, points@θ}}];

With[{rc = RuleCondition, cg = Compile`GetElement}, 
  rhsfunc2 = Hold@
            Compile[{{u, _Real, 2}, {τeff, _Real, 1}, {γ, _Real, 1}}, 
             Table[rhs2, {θ, -Pi, Pi, delta@θ}, {ω, ωb, ωt, delta@ω}], 
             RuntimeOptions -> EvaluateSymbolically -> False, CompilationTarget -> C] /. 
           OwnValues@rhs2 /. 
          u[theta_, omega_] :> 
           rc@(cg[u, Mod[#, points@θ - 1, 1], Mod[#2, points@ω - 1, 1]] & @@
               Round@rt@{theta, omega}) /. (coef : τeff | γ)[theta_] :> 
          rc@(cg[coef, First@Round@rttheta@{theta}]) /. DownValues@delta /. 
       DownValues@points /. Flatten[OwnValues /@ Unevaluated@{ωb, ωt}] // 
     ReleaseHold // Last];
T = 30;
ulstfunc2 = 
   NDSolveValue[{u'[t] == rhsfunc2[u[t], τefflst, γlst], u[0] == iclst2}, 
    u, {t, 0, T}, MaxSteps -> Infinity]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {36.177260, Null} *)

lst = Table[
   ListPlot3D[ulstfunc2[t]\[Transpose], PlotRange -> All, 
    DataRange -> {{-Pi, Pi}, {ωb, ωt}}], {t, 0, 5, 1/20}];    
ListAnimate@lst
```

[image]

Notice definitions of `σ1` etc. are not included here, please find them in the body of the question.

Comment: I notice that you use the same difference scheme in the d(xf)/dx as in my friend's Julia code. Such a subtle detail can really affect the stability very much? Anyway, thanks a lot!

Comment: @BobLin Yeah, surprising, but it's true. Notice this phenomenon is rather rare, before your question came out, [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/133315/1871) seems to be the only example in this site.

Comment: @BobLin If you're going to be doing a lot of numerical solution of PDEs for your work, you should get more general background on the topic.  One nice starting place is [Numerical Recipes](http://perso.fundp.ac.be/~amayer/Cours/ApprocheNumerique/chap19.pdf) by Press et al.

Comment: @xzczd Is it possible to apply your code to the PDE with f, which are interpolating function or user define function? In my second code, there are interpolating function like $τ_{eff}(θ)$ and $γ(θ)$. I want to apply your method to get the exact solution in the second example, but it seems to run quite too long.

Comment: I notice that the functions are always outside the the derivative. Something like `With[{u = u[t, θ, ω]}, 
  eq = D[u, t] == -ω D[ u, θ] - 
     1/L*τeff[θ] D[u, ω] + 
    γ[θ] D[ ω u, ω] + 
     γ[θ]D[ u, {ω, 2}];
  ic = u == 
     E^(-(ω^2 + (θ + π/
                4)^2)/(2 a^2))/(2  π a^2) /. t -> 0];` But it still very slow, when I run NDSolve.

Comment: I ran the solution with (t,0,1,0.1). It already takes 97sec, but I think there is no big difference between those two example, right? With (t,0,10,1), it might be 10 times longer I guess.

Comment: @bob Please check my update.

Comment: @xzczd Thanks! Here comes another problem. I have installed VS2017 and there is no problem to run your first example. But when I run your second one, there are some messages pop up like `A C compiler cannot be found on your system. Please consult the documentation to learn how to set up suitable compilers.`

Comment: @bob This should not happen. Did you remove `CompilationTarget` option and `// Last` in the first sample? BTW, personally I recommend using _TDM-GCC_, here's a Chinese tutorial for the configuration: https://note.youdao.com/share/?id=15144020fcbd5fc7e4bdefa5356668b4&type=note

Comment: I found the problem. When I use 11.3 ver, there is no error. When I run 10.3, then the error shows up. Maybe 10.3 ver. is not clever enough to find the C compiler automatically.

Comment: @bob As far as I know, Mathematica always has problem with Visual Studio released after it. (v10.3 is released in 2015.10. ) Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/41682/1871 https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/160006/1871

Comment: @xzczd Now I run in 11.3 and a message pops up. `CompiledFunction::rterr: -- Message text not found -- (compiledFunction2) (8)`. What's going on?

Comment: The problem appears when I run NDSolveValue.

Comment: @bob This depends on how you modified the code. Removing the `//Last` in the code might give you a hint.

Comment: @xzczd After removing //Last, I get `CompiledFunction::cfexe: Could not complete external evaluation; proceeding with uncompiled evaluation.`

Comment: @bob  Then as mentioned above, this depends on how you modified the code.

Comment: I simply include my definition of the function in my second code. Strange...

Comment: @xzczd I update the question. I copy both your code and my code. It does not work.

Comment: @bob ……You missed definition of `ct` and `fw` and `bw` and `delta`.

Comment: @xzczd Sorry...stupid mistake. Now it's fine. Thanks!