# Mathematica does not recognize c compiler

Tags: compile, windows, ccompilerdriver

I have Mathematica 11.1 and Windows 10 OS. I need to use c based compilation inside Mathematica, like `Compile[..., CompilationTarget -> "C", CompilationOptions -> \{"InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True}]`.

To do this, I have first downloaded Microsoft C++ Build Tools 2019. Then I have installed it. Finally, following answers on [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/41682/c-compilation-not-working-with-visual-studio-2013/41691#41691), I have modified the VisualStudioCompiler.m file, adding there
"2019" to the list of $VisualStudioVersions and the string

```
installPath["2019"] := installPathFromEnvironment["VS166COMNTOOLS"]
```

(the version of C++ build tools is 16.6, which is reflected in VS166...).

However, when launching

```
Needs["CCompilerDriver`"]
CCompilers[Full]
CCompilers[]
```

I get `{}`.

Could you please tell me what have I made wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Mathematica 11.0.1 here, worked OTB only w/ Visual Studio EXPRESS 2015. Tried 2019 and 2017 (also editing .m file) but they're not compatible. To download Express 2015, you have to sign up to the free Visual Studio subscription ando go to [https://my.visualstudio.com/Downloads?q=visual%20studio%202015&wt.mc_id=o~msft~vscom~older-downloads](https://my.visualstudio.com/Downloads?q=visual%20studio%202015&wt.mc_id=o%7Emsft%7Evscom%7Eolder-downloads)